# Specifying target directory when running msiexec in nsis

Tags: nsis, windows-installer

I am trying to install 7-Zip.msi using msiexec.  Whilst I can execute the msi using the following nsis command it defaults installation to C:\Program Files

```
ExecWait '"msiexec" /passive /i "$OUTDIR\<msi filename>.msi"'
```

I cannot find a way of specifying a custom destination directory for the install.

msiexec documentation suggests I can use TARGETDIR.  So I tried the below

```
SetOutPath "C:\Software\7-Zip"
DetailPrint "Installing 7-Zip to $OUTDIR" 
ExecWait '"msiexec" /passive /i "$OUTDIR\7-Zip.msi" TARGETDIR="$OUTDIR"'
```

But when I run the nsis exe I get no error, but 7-Zip has not been installed to the C:\Software\7-Zip directory.

Does anyone know how you specify a target installation directory when using msiexec?

Comment: Why only tag this with NSIS? It is not even really NSIS related.

Comment: "It is not even really NSIS related" - How can you be so sure of that.  Did you go through the NSIS ExecWait function call to see how it parses the supplied value?

Comment: ExecWait does not parse anything other than $variables (like most NSIS instructions) and then it just calls CreateProcess. The outermost set of quotes are removed by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
ExecWait '"msiexec" /passive /i "C:\Temp\7-Zip.msi" INSTALLDIR="$OUTDIR"'
```

Using `INSTALLDIR` solved the issue. Seems as though `INSTALLDIR` is a property specific to the 7-Zip.msi. Some msi files use `TARGETDIR`.

Comment: `TARGETDIR` is the standard property but unfortunately many(most?) setups don't respect that and define their own property for the installation directory.